# Font problems with pslatex

Tags: pdf, ps

I am not really familiar with `pslatex`, I usually prefer `pdflatex`.

I prepared a document, compiled with `pdflatex` many times and everything works perfectly. Now I have to recompile it with `pslatex`.

I converted the images from pdf to ps and tried to run `pslatex myfile.tex`.

Everything works, but when I try to open the `dvi` file I get uncomprensible text.

For example:

```
Random Spanning ...
```

is

```
Q'ncnl Ro'nnlnf ...
```

I guess it is a problem related to font packages or something similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: why do you want to use `pslatex`. You can still use `pdflatex` with `\usepackage{mathptmx,helvet,courier}` to get the same fonts.

Comment: pslatex is imposed by other people for obscure reasons.
unfortunately I have to fix the problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is only a problem with the dvi viewer (which one?). What happens when you generate a ps with dvips and open the file with gsview?

Comment: I using evince on Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow I didn't even realise `pslatex` was still distributed with texlive. There can't be any good reason for using that now (I wrote it:-)

Comment: Seems that some journals are still using pslatex

Comment: pslatex itself is just a thin script around latex changing the default fonts. Rather than get your dvi viewer to understand those fonts it may be easier to use dvips then ps2pdf to get pdf and then use your pdf viewer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what appears to be a localised font installation issue.
